# What do I and V mean in C = It/V?

Tags: capacitor, dc, rectifier, ripple, smoothing-capacitor

I am trying to determine what value capacitor I need to put after the full wave rectifier to get a smooth voltage for charging my battery. However, I don't understand which current and voltage do the variables I and V mean in the equation for determining the capacitance of the capacitor. 
$$C = It / V $$
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Current, and voltage. For sizing a reservoir cap take I as the maximum load current, V as the ripple voltage you can tolerate, and t as the time between peaks (half a cycle) to get a cap with a small safety margin.

Comment: Your assumption is false. a battery is already a capacitor of >> 10k Farads with ESR. they use 3 phase for optimum ripple. vs cost.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 A battery is not a capacitor, and I feel it's somewhat misleading to say that it is, even as a metaphor.

Comment: @Hearth You have much to learn on simulations. look up my answers on this topic It also includes an ideal cell V and ESR , actually many RC networks.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sure, there's a capacitance in the equivalent model if you want to go to that length, but saying that a battery *is* a capacitor or arguably even that it *contains* a capacitor is still wrong. I had a student a few weeks ago who was very confused because they thought that a capacitor was just a very small rechargeable battery, and I want to avoid encouraging that sort of misconception.

Comment: @Hearth , no matter you think, the correct way to model a battery starts with an electrolytic capacitor. Adding another of much smaller capacitance does nothing to affect charge transfer rate or efficiency.  Pls correct your perception on this.  The ESR rises sharply as charge voltage drops below 10% of mean.  Compute It/V from Vmax to Vmin and convert from Amp Hours to Amp-seconds

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I think you have entirely the wrong idea of what I am saying. I am not arguing whether a capacitor is necessary here or not, I am saying that, from a didactic standpoint, the phrase "a battery is already a capacitor" is misleading and should be avoided.

Comment: Ok but you still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what those guys are talking about, who "they" are, or how 3-phase got into this.

Your equation describes the charging and discharging of a capacitor with a constant current.  (A different equation (the one with the natural logarithm e in it) describes a capacitor interacting with a constant resistance.)

For a ripple calculation, V is the ripple amplitude in volts peak-to-peak, and I is the discharge current in amps.  C is the capacitor value in farads.  For a full-wave circuit in the US, t is the ripple period, 1 / 120 Hz, or 8.33 ms.

Example:  9 V regulator circuit has a minimum input voltage requirement of 11 V.  Power transformer secondary voltage = 12.6 V, load current = 0.5 A, and the minimum output voltage (the negative peaks of the ripple component of the output) = 11 V.

Vpeak = 12.6 x sqrt(2) = 17.82 V

2 bridge diode forward voltage crops = 2 x 0.8 V = 1.6 V

Filter capacitor positive peak voltage = 17.82 - 1.6 = 16.22 V

Discharge ripple voltage = 16.22 - 11.0 = 5.22 V

EC=IT

C = i x t / E

C = (0.5 x .00833) / 5.22 = 798 uF

Because the ripple waveform has sinusoidal characteristics, this result is a very close approximation of the theoretically perfect minimum capacitor value.  The perfect value always is slightly smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of two basic formulas of capacitors C=Q/V and Q=It.
for I you must consider maximum Current and V is ripple voltage. 
In your case, it's important to consider the impedance of capacitor and its load effect with battery resistance.
for more information check this website:

https://www.johnsavesenergy.com/capacitive-charger